# Application + service

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в одном проекте есть activity и service, как сделать чтобы когда удаляешь процесс, удалялась только activity, а service оставался?

Вот полный код MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
final String serviceName = "ua.intsystems.screenturn.action.startforeground";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ListView listV = new ListView(this);

    Switch s = new Switch(this);
    s.setLayoutParams(viewParams);
    if (s != null)
        s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    if(isServiceRunning())
        s.setChecked(true);
    else
        s.setChecked(false);

    /*View view[] = {s};

    AdapterView adapter = new AdapterView(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, view);
    listV.setAdapter(adapter);*/

    linLayout.addView(s);

    setContentView(linLayout, linParams);

}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScreenOnService.class);
    intent.setAction(serviceName);

    if(isChecked)
        startService(intent);
    else
        stopService(intent);
}

private boolean isServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceName.equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

И ScreenOnService.class

```
public class ScreenOnService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

final String LOG_TAG = "Logs: ";
private SensorManager sm;
private float x;
private float y;
private float z;
private float distance;
private float far;
private float light;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private Sensor mProximity;
private Sensor mLight;
private PowerManager pm;
private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
private KeyguardManager key;
private KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock keyLock;
private boolean continueWhile = true;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mProximity = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    mLight = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
    sm.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sm.registerListener(this, mProximity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sm.registerListener(this, mLight, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    key = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    keyLock = key.newKeyguardLock("TAG");

    pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE), "TAG");

    far = mProximity.getMaximumRange();
    distance=far;

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, getText(R.string.app_name),
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ScreenOnService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.app_name),
            getText(R.string.app_name), pendingIntent);
    startForeground(1, notification);
    /*Notification note = new Notification( 0, null, System.currentTimeMillis() );
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    startForeground(42, note);*/
    someTask();
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    continueWhile = false;
    sm.unregisterListener(this);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBind");
    return null;
}

void someTask() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(continueWhile) {
                //Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 10);
                if (!pm.isScreenOn()) {
                    keyLock.reenableKeyguard();
                    if(distance<far && light>= 5) {
                        keyLock.disableKeyguard();
                        wakeLock.acquire();
                        distance=far;
                        /*try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }*/
                        wakeLock.release();
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Screen ON");
                    }
                }
            }
        /*
            for (int i = 1; i<=5; i++) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "i = " + i);
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }*/
            //stopSelf();
        }
    }).start();
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(!pm.isScreenOn())
    switch(event.sensor.getType()){
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            x=event.values[0];
            y=event.values[1];
            z=event.values[2];
        break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY:
            distance=event.values[0];
            Log.d("Distance: ", Float.toString(distance));
        break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT:
            light=event.values[0];
            Log.d("Light: ", Float.toString(light));
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

}
```

Comment: А как убиваете процесс?

Comment: Убиваю с помощью встроеного диспетчера задач, там отображается activity, я его в сторошу сдвигаю и процесс заершается Activity вместе с Service, хотя на самом телефоне есть встроенные приложения у которых сервсы работают отдельно от activity

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить соответствующий флаг в intent, стартующий сервис:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YoursService.class);
//указываем, что сервис не должен зависеть от жизненного цикла активити
intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
startService(intent);
```

**Обновление**

Если я правильно понял то, что гугл выдаёт на этот счёт, то единственный способ не дать умереть сервису при смерти приложения - вывод Notification из сервиса через

```
int notificationId=10;
startForeground(notificationId, notification);
```

Comment: Насколько я понял, это вот этот мануал:

 http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/, пробывал не помог

Comment: Да, оттуда как раз. Обновил ответ

Comment: пробывал не помогает вот код

     Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, getText(R.string.app_name),
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.app_name),
                getText(R.string.app_name), pendingIntent);
        startForeground(1, notification);

Comment: @Kl0nLutiy, да, тут вот спрашивают как процесс убиваете? У меня, насколько я помню, когда я делал, как выше описано, всё работало как надо - активити помирало, а сервис продолжал работать.

Comment: Добавил полный код